# repeated select with ng-option binding issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the ng-options.
I have a modal where there are repeated select with `ng-options`. The modal getting the data from its parent view. After the first open (the modal) it is working good, but after I open it again it doesn't binding the last selected value in the `select` field.

**modal.html**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div data-ng-repeat="filter in filters track by $index">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>{{filter.column_label}}</label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedFilter"
                    ng-options="obj.value for obj in filter.column_enums track by obj.key "
                    ng-change="change($index)">
                <option value="">Please choose</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="setFilter()">save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">cancel</button>
</div>
```

**modalController.js**

```
app.controller('filterController', function($scope, scope, $uibModalInstance){

    $scope.selectedFilter = scope.parentData.selectedValues; //first time it is empty
    $scope.filters = scope.parentData.filters;

    $scope.change = function (index){

        $scope.selectedFilter[index] = this.selectedFilter;
    };

    $scope.setFilter = function (){
        scope.parentData.selectedValues = $scope.selectedFilter;

        $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**parentController**

```
$scope.parentData = [
    {
        column_enums : [
        {key: 1, value: 'val1'},
        {key: 2, value: 'val2'},
        //more objects here
        ],
        column_label : 'someLabel'
    },
    {
        column_enums : [
        {key: 3, value: 'val3'},
        {key: 4, value: 'val4'},
        //more objects here
        ],
        column_label : 'someLabel2'
    },
];

$scope.openFilters = function (index){
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modules/modals/rmodal.html',
            controller: 'modalController',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve :{
                scope: function(){
                    return $scope;
                }
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: plz provide plunker

Comment: scope.parentData.selectedValues; = $scope.selectedFilter; should be scope.parentData.selectedValues = $scope.selectedFilter;  Remove the erroneous ';'

Comment: why are using change method? remove options tag inside select tag...